# SQL - getting record with maximum value

Tags: sql, max

I am trying to retrieve the product with the highest price:

```
SELECT ProductName, Price 
FROM [Products]
ORDER BY Price DESC
LIMIT 1
```

I wanted to know if there is another way of doing this in a more efficient way, with MAX for example.

Comment: Which database please? the features and syntax for solutions differ by platform

Comment: LIMIT implies MySQL, but `[Products]` implies MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MAX and GROUP BY

```
SELECT ProductName, MAX(Price) [Price]
FROM [Products]
GROUP BY ProductName
ORDER BY MAX(Price) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've always done it with the following

SELECT top 1 Name
FROM tableName
ORDER BY Price DESC

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 * from [Products] order by Price desc
```

Comment: This will return all products, OP only wants the most expensive one.

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding. please check now

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TOP 1` but you always have to consider the possibility of having a tie, so:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES ProductName, Price 
FROM [Products]
ORDER BY Price DESC
```